# ¿Como accedo a un objeto que se obtiene en el evento onClick del boton desde fuera del evento?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

He intentado de muchas maneras acceder a los datos guardados en productosAntes fuera del evento onClick del boton, con promesas, async y await y no he podido. Necesito poder utilizar estos datos en la funcion miFunción que a su vez, dentro de ella llama a la funcion out_editar, el problema es que debo acceder a los datos fuera del evento on click para que la funcion out_editar se ejecute solamente una vez y no se ejecute cada vez que la función miFuncion se ejecuta. Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
const btn_actualizar = document.getElementById('btn_actualizar');
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="btn_modal_"]');
let productosAntes = null;

//Agregar evento clic a cada botón
botones.forEach(function (boton) {
    boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Acciones a realizar cuando se haga clic en un botón
        console.log('Se hizo clic en el botón con ID: ' + boton.id);

        // Obtener los datos del producto de la fila de la tabla

        const pro_antes = {
            idProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-id-producto'),
            nombreProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-nombre-producto'),
            marcaProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-marca'),
            disponibilidadProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-disponibilidad'),
            procedenciaProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-procedencia'),
            cantidadProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-cantidad'),
            presentacionProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-presentacion'),
            pucProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-puc'),
            puvProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-puv')
        }

        productosAntes = pro_antes;
        
        miFuncion(productosAntes);
        // Imprimir el valor actualizado de idProducto        
    });
});


console.log(productosAntes);

const miFuncion = (producto) => {

    console.log('El botón modal ha sido presionado antes de editar', producto.id_Producto, producto.nombre_producto, producto.marca, producto.disponibilidad, producto.procedencia, producto.cantidad, producto.presentacion, producto.puc, producto.puv);

    btn_editar.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('guardar cambios presionado');
        out_editar(id_Producto);
    });
}

const out_editar = (id_obtener) => {
    console.log("El id es: ", id_obtener);
    console.log('El botón modal ha sido presionado después de editar', in_nombre_producto.value, in_marca.value, in_disponibilidad.value, in_procedencia.value, in_cantidad.value, in_presentacion.value, in_puc.value, in_puv.value);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Promesas para asegurarte que el valor de `productosAntes` esté actualizado antes de llamar a la función `out_editar`:

```
const btn_actualizar = document.getElementById('btn_actualizar');
const botones = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="btn_modal_"]');
let productosAntes = null;

// Agregar evento clic a cada botón
botones.forEach(function (boton) {
    boton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        // Acciones a realizar cuando se haga clic en un botón
        console.log('Se hizo clic en el botón con ID: ' + boton.id);

        // Obtener los datos del producto de la fila de la tabla
        const pro_antes = {
            idProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-id-producto'),
            nombreProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-nombre-producto'),
            marcaProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-marca'),
            disponibilidadProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-disponibilidad'),
            procedenciaProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-procedencia'),
            cantidadProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-cantidad'),
            presentacionProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-presentacion'),
            pucProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-puc'),
            puvProducto : boton.getAttribute('data-puv')
        }

        productosAntes = pro_antes;
        
        // Utilizar una promesa para asegurarse de que productosAntes esté actualizado antes de llamar a miFuncion
        Promise.resolve()
            .then(() => {
                return miFuncion(productosAntes);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    });
});

console.log(productosAntes);

const miFuncion = (producto) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('El botón modal ha sido presionado antes de editar', producto.idProducto, producto.nombreProducto, producto.marcaProducto, producto.disponibilidadProducto, producto.procedenciaProducto, producto.cantidadProducto, producto.presentacionProducto, producto.pucProducto, producto.puvProducto);
        
        // Resolver la promesa después de que la función btn_editar sea presionada
        btn_editar.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('guardar cambios presionado');
            out_editar(producto.idProducto);
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

const out_editar = (id_obtener) => {
    console.log("El id es: ", id_obtener);
    console.log('El botón modal ha sido presionado después de editar', in_nombre_producto.value, in_marca.value, in_disponibilidad.value, in_procedencia.value, in_cantidad.value, in_presentacion.value, in_puc.value, in_puv.value);
}
```